# I need to limit my program not to accept any decimal values in my program

Tags: c++, functional-programming, decimal

I am instructed that I have to reject any decimal and I need to re enter the number again.I tried this code but still it just goes to the whole process before acknowledging the error. Try the program and judge me :D here's my code:

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
#include<limits>
using namespace std;



int getInt()
    {
    int m=0;


    while (!(cin >> m))
        {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        cout << "Please input a proper 'whole' number: " ;

        }
    return (m);
    }


int main()
{
    double x;
    int q,w,e,choice;
    cout<<"Welcome! This program will sort out the integers you will input!\nPlease input number of integers: ";
    cin>>q;
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    int* inc= new int[q];
    int* dec= new int[q];
    for(int p=1;p<=q;++p)
    {
        w=p;
        e=p;

    cout<<"Input integer number "<<p<<": ";
    x =getInt();

    while(e>0 && inc[e-1]>x)
    {
        inc[e]=inc[e-1];
        e--;
    }

    while(w>0 && dec[w-1]<x)
    {
        dec[w]=dec[w-1];
        w--;
    }
    inc[e]=x;
    dec[w]=x;
    }

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"What order do you prefer? Input 1 for increasing and 2 if decreasing.\nChoice: ";
    cin>>choice;
    while(choice<1 || choice>2)
    {
        cout<<"Please input a correct choice! Try again!\nChoice: ";
        cin>>choice;
    }
    if(choice==1)
    {

    for(int i=0;i<q;++i)
    cout<<inc[i]<<"\t";
    cout<<endl;
    }
    else
    {

    for(int i=1;i<=q;++i)
    cout<<dec[i]<<"\t";
    cout<<endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

hoping for your help :)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What can I do to restrict it that no decimal is allowed to be entered

Comment: @darrelpinga do you mean floating point numbers?

Comment: no. I mean when you input 2.3 it will reject it and will make you input a whole number

Comment: try making a copy of the number you want to test and casting it to an int and then back to a decimal, and then check for equality. If they are equal, you have an int, if they are not, you have a decimal.

Comment: @darrelpinga those are floating point numbers

Comment: I'd take the input as a `std::string` and use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). If it throws, the user didn't enter a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a copy of the number you want to test and casting it to an int and then back to a double, and then check for equality. If they are equal, you have an int, if they are not, you have a decimal:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a = 5;
    double c = 5.5;
    double b = a;
    bool test1 = (double)((int)b) == a; //true!
    b = c;
    bool test2 = (double)((int)b) == c; //false!
    cout << test1 << endl;
    cout << test2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Wrote this answer a long time ago, it is very hacky and will not work on all inputs. Use `std::stoi` and check if it throws as the comment suggests instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using modulo.
Just an idea, hope it helps.

```
bool flag = false;
While (flag == false){
cin>>number;

if ((number % 1) != 0){
flag = false;
}
else{
flag = true;
}
cin.clear();
}
```